# Momentum when pausing a tween in TweenMax

Tags: javascript, gsap

Is it possible to apply momentum when pausing a tween in **`TweenMax`**?

Using **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0t0v5k9/)** as an example, would it be possible to slow the box down over a time span of one second when paused.

```
TweenMax.to('.example', 5, {
    x: 1000,
    ease: Linear.easeNone,
    repeat: -1
});
```

I know this could be accomplished be creating a new tween, but it would be nice if there was a build in method for accomplishing this.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like this built into **`TweenMax`** itself but you can raise your query in the **[GSAP Forums](http://greensock.com/forums/forum/11-gsap/)** and I am sure people over there would give you a better answer on this, perhaps even a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, there is a **[ThrowPropsPlugin](http://greensock.com/throwpropsplugin)** provided by **GSAP** which does deal with *momentum*-based tweens.

And this **ThrowPropsPlugin** internally uses **[VelocityTracker](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Utils/VelocityTracker/)** (which is again, a utility provided by GSAP) which you can directly hook into, using its [`.track()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Utils/VelocityTracker/track/) method and then anytime you want to get the computed velocity, you can use [`.getVelocity()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Utils/VelocityTracker/getVelocity/) method of the same.

Unfortunately, I don't have a demo for you but you can take a look at the [ThrowPropsPlugin demos](http://greensock.com/throwpropsplugin) and take it from there.

Having said that though, **ThrowPropsPlugin** is part of **[Club GreenSock](http://greensock.com/club/)**.

Hope this helps.